# How to get the position of (P3D)window?

Tags: processing

the p3d window ,not 2d ..............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need the position of the window to achieve your goal. But if you really want to get it, you can get it through the `surface` variable.

Here's how to do it with the default renderer:

```java
import processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
  PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas sc = (PSurfaceAWT.SmoothCanvas)surface.getNative();
  println(sc.getFrame().getX() + ", " + sc.getFrame().getY());
}
```

And here's how to do it with the `P3D` renderer:

```java
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
}

void draw() {
  GLWindow glw = (GLWindow)surface.getNative();
  println(glw.getX() + ", " + glw.getX());
}
```

Comment: @venitable I'm not really sure what you're asking. Feel free to post a new question along with a [mcve] showing where you're stuck, and we'll go from there.